# How to get metadata from HealthKit?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm working on an application that reads different health data from `HealthKit` application.

So far I managed to get the DOB, most recent records of height, weight and blood glucose.

What I still need is how to get the metadata for these objects, specifically I need to get the date/time the record was entered.

For example, to get the record of the height, I'm using this method:

```
func updateHeight()
{
// 1. Construct an HKSampleType for Height
let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)

// 2. Call the method to read the most recent Height sample
self.healthManager?.readMostRecentSample(sampleType, completion: { (mostRecentHeight, error) -> Void in

  if( error != nil )
  {
    println("Error reading height from HealthKit Store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return;
  }

  var heightLocalizedString = self.kUnknownString;
  self.height = mostRecentHeight as? HKQuantitySample;
  // 3. Format the height to display it on the screen
  if let meters = self.height?.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.meterUnit()) {
    let heightFormatter = NSLengthFormatter()
    heightFormatter.forPersonHeightUse = true;
    heightLocalizedString = heightFormatter.stringFromMeters(meters);
  }


  // 4. Update UI. HealthKit use an internal queue. We make sure that we interact with the UI in the main thread
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.heightLabel.text = heightLocalizedString
  });
})

}
```

As you notice I'm creating an `HKSampleType` constant then pass it to a method called `readMostRecentSample` which takes this parameter and then returns the most recent record for this sample type.

I tried to print line the returned object and I've got this output:

> 1.9 m "Health" metadata: { HKWasUserEntered = 1; } 2015-05-17 10:11:00 +0300 2015-05-17 10:11:00 +0300

As you see the output includes the metadata of the object, but actually I couldn't extract only the date.

Also I found that there is a property of the object called `metadata`, I printed it out but it only retrieved me a boolean of whether the data was entered by the user (manually) or automatically from a third party:
`println(self.height?.metadata)`

The output was:
`[HKWasUserEntered = 1]`

I would be grateful and thankful if someone can give me any idea of how to extract the metadata of each object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `HKSample` object and its subclasses like `HKQuantitySample` have 2 fields that store date information : `startDate` and `endDate`. If you are trying to get the date this is where you should look.

> Some samples—for example, body temperature—represent a single point in
> time. For these samples, both the start and the end date are the same,
> because they both refer to the point in time when the sample was
> taken.
>
> Other samples—for example, step count—represent data over a time
> interval. Here, the sample should use different start and end dates.
> These dates mark the beginning and end of the sample’s time interval,
> respectively.

From the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSample_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/HKSample/startDate